# Passing std::ofstream object as argument to class method

Tags: c++, ofstream

As previous questions have been answered, the way to pass a `std::ofstream` object as a function argument seems to be to instead pass a reference: `std::ofstream&`.

Whilst this solution compiles, the resulting output is not equivalent to creating an std::ofstream object within the method then calling write().

The code below does not give the correct output:

In **main.cpp**:

```
std::ofstream file(path + "output.stubs");
stub->writeRaw(file); //stub is a pointer to an object of class Stub
file.close();
```

In **Stub.cpp**:

```
void Stub::writeRaw(std::ofstream& file) {
    file.write((char*)this, sizeof(*this));
}
```

The correct output is given by both changing **Stub.cpp** to:

```
void Stub::writeRaw(void) {
    std::ofstream file(path + "output.stubs");
    file.write((char*)this, sizeof(*this));
    file.close();
}
```

or writing the object to the file in main instead of calling a class method.

Any help on this behaviour would be greatly appreciated!

**EDIT**

Some context for the class Stub:

**Stub.hpp**

```
#pragma once

#include <iostream>
#include <ios>
#include <fstream>

#include "constants.hpp"
#include "DataTypes.hpp"


class Stub {
private:
    StubHeader header;
    StubIntrinsicCoordinates intrinsic;
    StubPayload payload;

public:
    Stub(void);
    virtual ~Stub(void);

    StubHeader getHeader(void);
    StubIntrinsicCoordinates getIntrinsicCoordinates(void);
    StubPayload getPayload(void);

    void setHeader(StubHeader stub_header);
    void setIntrinsicCoordinates(StubIntrinsicCoordinates stub_intrinsic);
    void setPayload(StubPayload stub_payload);

    void print(void);
    void writeRaw(std::ofstream& file);
};
```

And the relevant data types are defined as follows:

```
struct StubHeader {
    uint8_t bx;
    uint8_t nonant;
};

struct StubIntrinsicCoordinates {
    uint8_t strip;
    uint8_t column;
    int crossterm;
};

struct StubPayload {
    bool valid;
    int r;
    int z;
    int phi;
    int8_t alpha;
    int8_t bend;
    uint8_t layer;
    bool barrel;
    bool module;
};
```

**EDIT 2**

The (toy) code to read the stub is as follows:

```
std::ifstream r(path + "output.stubs");
Stub s;
r.read((char*)&s, sizeof(s));
s.print();
```

Only one stub is written to the file as this was a test of functionality. The print function for the Stub class is as follows:

```
void Stub::print(void) {
    std::cout << "----- Header -----" << '\n';
    std::cout << "bx: " << std::dec << (int)header.bx << '\n';
    std::cout << "nonant: " << std::dec << (int)header.nonant << '\n';
    std::cout << "----- Intrinsic Coordinates -----" << '\n';
    std::cout << "strip: " << std::dec << (int)intrinsic.strip << '\n';
    std::cout << "column: " << std::dec << (int)intrinsic.column << '\n';
    std::cout << "crossterm: " << std::dec << (int)intrinsic.crossterm << '\n';
    std::cout << "----- Payload -----" << '\n';
    std::cout << "valid: " << std::boolalpha << payload.valid << '\n';
    std::cout << "r: " << std::dec << (int)payload.r << '\n';
    std::cout << "z: " << std::dec << (int)payload.z << '\n';
    std::cout << "phi: " << std::dec << (int)payload.phi << '\n';
    std::cout << "alpha: " << std::dec << (int)payload.alpha << '\n';
    std::cout << "bend: " << std::dec << (int)payload.bend << '\n';
    std::cout << "layer: " << std::dec << (int)payload.layer << '\n';
    std::cout << "barrel: " << std::boolalpha << payload.barrel << '\n';
    std::cout << "module: " << std::boolalpha << payload.module << "\n\n";
}
```

**EDIT 3**

For completeness and transparency, please find below the exact code for **main.cpp**:

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    Geometry g;
    g.generateModuleLUTs();
    g.generateCorrectionLUTs();
    std::vector<std::array<Stub*, PAYLOAD_WIDTH> > all_stubs;
    std::vector<Module> modules = g.getData(); 
    for (int i = 0; i < LINK_NUMBER; i++) {
        LinkGenerator link_gen;
        LinkFormatter link_formatter(link_gen.run());
        StubFormatter stub_formatter(link_formatter.run(), i);
        std::array<Stub*, PAYLOAD_WIDTH> stubs = stub_formatter.run(modules);
        CoordinateCorrector coordinate_corrector(stubs);
        all_stubs.push_back(coordinate_corrector.run());
    }
    std::ofstream f(path + "output.stubs");
    all_stubs[0][0]->writeRaw(f);
    all_stubs[0][0]->print();
    std::ifstream r(path + "output.stubs");
    Stub s;
    r.read((char*)&s, sizeof(s));
    s.print();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In what sense is the output not correct?

Comment: hi what is the expected output what do you have ?

Comment: The member variables of the object when reading the file are not equal to the those of the stub when it is created. Using the method of creating an ```std::ofstream``` in the class method gives the correct memeber variables upon reading the file.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. Is it possible that you shouldn't be serialising like this in the first place, and are therefore running into undefined behaviour? What are the contents of `this`? Present a [mcve]. We can already see that this is not your real code because you're missing a `;` and so the code would not compile.

Comment: Sorry, still not a [mcve] that we can use to reproduce. But you can rest assured that passing a reference to a `std::ofstream` doesn't change the behaviour of the `std::ofstream`.

Comment: I have added some extra context to the question, including the full header file for the Stub class. The strange behaviour seems to come from passing the file object to the method, as it is possible to write the object to file if the file object is constructed within the method.

Comment: Again, that is not how C++ works, so you have undefined behaviour somewhere and should focus on locating that. e.g. how do you observe this behaviour? We see no reading code.

Comment: Is it deliberate that you do not open your files in binary mode?

Comment: Please, instead of a behemoth of sequential edits, present a comprehensive and self-contained [mcve]. You should already have one on your computer if you've been debugging!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit maybe the OP is invoking UB by casting `this` to a char*? That definitely seems sketchy, but can't find any resources that confirms whether this is UB either way.

Comment: @Chipster That should be okay

Comment: Writing objects with virtual functions to files is not a good idea.

Comment: Raw write/read of an object to/from a file that has pointers is not going to round trip well (and the file likely won't be cross-platform portable, due to padding).  The `Stub` object has a virtual function table, which is (typically) a pointer as part of the object.  So a raw write/read will do Bad Things™.

Comment: Ah yeah there you go

Comment: I have found the problem, I was not closing the ```std::ofstream``` object before constructing the ```std::ifstream``` object to read the file back again. Correcting this caused the code to behave as it should.

Comment: Thank you @LightnessRacesinOrbit for your suggestions and guidance. This was my first time asking a question here and you have taught me much on what is a good structure for a question and what is best to include.

Comment: @D.Monk You're welcome. You could also consider taking the Tour and reading some of the guides in the Help Centre. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bug in the code was that I was not calling `file.close()` before constructing the `std::ifstream` object to read the file again. This was the cause of the unexpected behaviour.

Writing a class to file using `this` seems to be valid, although it is important that you are careful and know exactly what you want to write to a file.

Thank you to everyone who commented and helped to answer this question!

Comment: I will accept this as the answer once I am able to.

Comment: Just to reiterate, your code is _not_ safe because you're bytewise-serialising something with virtual member functions, and your results are otherwise unportable due to padding & endianness, and your results are otherwise prone to being wrong due to opening your files in text mode.